# How can I create a forward proxy that runs on a server with no exposed ports?

Tags: go, http, networking, proxy, connection

I am trying to build a web scraping utility that allows anyone to run a program and have their computer act as a forward proxy, mainly to get around IP blocking. The high level overview of this would work as follows:

```
Requester --sends http request--> Centralized server --distributes request to random client--> 
Client --sends request to target server--> Target server --responds back down to requester--> 
Client --> Centralized server -> Requester
```

The tricky part of this is allowing the client to act as a forward proxy, without actually exposing any ports (as I want this to have no tricky networking setup, e.g. port forwarding). Additionally, I believe it makes sense for the Centralized server to look like a typical forward proxy to to the Requester, so it could work with the following code:

```golang
func main() {
    proxyURL, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    httpClient := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
        },
    }
    response, err := httpClient.Get("https://example.com/")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("Response status:", response.Status)
}
```

My original design involved having each client open a websocket connection to the server, thus removing the need for them to have exposed ports. Then, raw HTTP requests would be sent to the client, who would relay the request/response to/from the target server. However, I've been having alot of trouble getting it working properly. Here is my attempt:

```golang
// I don't know what the implementation of this would be.
type WSClient interface {
    io.Reader
    io.Writer
    io.Closer
}

func main() {
    var wsConn WSClient
    proxy := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        client, _, err := w.(http.Hijacker).Hijack()
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(502)
            fmt.Fprint(w, err)
            return
        }
        client.Write([]byte("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"))

        go func() {
            _, err = io.Copy(wsConn, client)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
            client.Close()
        }()
        go func() {
            _, err := io.Copy(client, wsConn)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
            wsConn.Close()
        }()
    }
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(proxy))
}
```

I don't really know where to go from here, nor does this feel like the right way to accomplish my goal of a super easy-to-setup forward proxy. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction, or give me some code samples to help me get closer to my desired functionality?

Edit: Some people have mentioned that without opening ports, I cannot receive any requests to forward. I am hoping to send the requests via a web socket opened by the client, thus bypassing this restriction.

Comment: If the client can't expose any ports, it can't receive any requests to forward. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the proxies request originate locally (and I mean internally vs. over any network connection, even from the loopback), you are going to have listeners, which by your definition, I think would be "exposed".

I think you mean "exposed" ports as in it listens for inbound connections, the classic approach is to have have the proxy server setup on as a bastion, with one network interface on the internet and one on the intranet.

Your proxy listens on the intranet, and only makes outbound connections on the internet.

By definition, a web proxy (forward or reverse) has to listen for a request.

Comment: So is there no way I can open a connection, thus ‘exposing’ a process without exposing any ports? I was hoping I could solve this by using a web socket or something

Comment: Exposed could mean different things, so this comes down to what you are comfortable with (or did someone else give you this criteria?). For example, in a corporate network, if you had DHCP "fixed" assignment (IT gave your desktop the same IP address all the time, and nobody else...) then you could have the proxy server also have a firewall that allowed only connections from your desktop. 

To me, that wouldn't be "exposed", because the system wouldn't let anyone else connect to the port listener.

Comment: If by web socket, you mean you could also control the desktop's opening port, then you could even have the firewall be: only from this port-from this ip address. That would mean even if someone was casually messing around on your desktop browser, they would still be rejected (unless they got lucky).